# Do an "Is" condition in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to do an "IS" condition in xaml?

```
<Condition 
    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Type}" 
    Value="MyNamespace.MyClass" />
```

There is no property called Type on the class I need.  There is the ever-present GetType() method, but I don't know how to call that here to make the condition comparison.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put in a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to do that logic, you can pass the type to compare as [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx) (use [`x:Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx)) and return `true` or `false` (set the `Condition.Value` to `true`).